# I have written code for card slider in html,css and js. I need to use that in angular components. But I'm stuck with adding js file

Tags: angular

**This is my html code. I've added that in app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card active"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

**This is my js code**

```
let holder = document.querySelectorAll('.container')[0],
cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
let preActiveCard = cards[1];
let nextActiveCard = cards[2];
function scrollLeft() {
  holder.classList.remove('next');
  holder.classList.remove('reset');
  holder.classList.add('next');
  preActiveCard.classList.remove('active');
  nextActiveCard.classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(reset, 1200);
}
function reset() {
  holder.classList.remove('next');
  holder.classList.add('reset');
  preActiveCard.classList.add('active');
  nextActiveCard.classList.remove('active');
}
setInterval(scrollLeft, 1500);
```

**I've added that in assets\js\custom.js
How to add the js code in components to make the slider work**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare const scrollLeft: any;
declare const reset: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
   scrollLeft()

  }
  // public loadScript(url: string) {
  //   const body = <HTMLDivElement> document.body;
  //   const script = document.createElement('script');
  //   script.innerHTML = '';
  //   script.src = url;
  //   script.async = false;
  //   script.defer = true;
  //   body.appendChild(script);
  // }

}
```

**This is my component.ts file**

Comment: you will find your answer here

Comment: why didn't you put this in app.component.ts?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the angular tutorial (https://angular.io/tutorial). In Angular you do not provide component based logic from assets.

Comment: I have separate component file, I've called this function scrollleft() and reset() in ngInit(). But its not working. @chana

Comment: Can you share the link @gem007bd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your JS function in the ngOnit function. That should run your JS code on page load without any error. But the best solution is to convert the JS code to angular

Answer (score 0):

You have a controller for that component: app.component.ts

You should put your functions there.

Comment: I have called the js function, in the component.ts file                                              
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 declare const scrollLeft: any;
 declare const reset: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit { constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
   scrollLeft()
   }
   }
 }